# Need a Generic way to Create SEO friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-routing, seo

I have searched a lot and implemented many many Regular Expressions in my `.htaccess` file but can not succeed. How to find a generic way to make my URL SEO friendly?

Currently this is in my `.htaccess` file:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I need to do is to change a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/abc/index.php?page=boats_for_sale
```

to this:

```
http://localhost/abc/boats_for_sale
```

Similarly, I want to hide all query strings in my URL.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: does it have to be .htaccess or you are ok with other solution to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like that it work :

## URL rewriting module activation

```
# Avoids problems with mod_rewrite
    Options +FollowSymlinks
# Activate rewriting module
    RewriteEngine on
# Set base URL directory rewrites
    RewriteBase /
```

## Rewriting url parameters

```
RewriteRule ^abc/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ abc/index.php?page=$1
```

Plz read the rewrite mod bible : 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html